# HTML img align attribute vs CSS float

Tags: html, css, browser, web

I read that the align attribute of `<img>` is deprecated in HTML 4.01. I'm just curious about one thing, the align attribute does the same thing as CSS float?

Comment: Have you tried both to see the results?

Comment: Since it is deprecated, I wouldn't even wonder that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `align` attribute does distinctly different things depending on what value you give it. Some of those things have been replaced by `float`, others by `vertical-align`.